# SSH request timeout every time AFTER Mac OS update

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

I previously had no trouble logging in until my Mac recently updated. Since then, the terminal always times out and can't connect.

ssh -Y -p 65492 username@141.xxx.xxx.xxx

I get the following:

"ssh: connect to host 141.xxx.xxx.xxx port 65492: Operation timed out"

I'm pretty new to Mac so was unaware that this update would cause this.

Thank you!

Comment: The message means that the Mac can not find the host 141… : did you check your network parameters ? Some may have been resetted during upgrade. Do you use X11 (-Y parameter) ? What was updated : Client Mac or server Mac or both ?